# Sharepoint as a WCM - What about Source Control

Tags: svn, sharepoint-2010

Some of my coleagues develop a public facing website using Sharepoint WCM.

Is it possible to put the html-content of the site under source control? I do not talk about webparts and extensions, but plain masterPages and Contentsites.

I have the impression that html ends up in the sharepoint-database. That would make it impossible for us to have the source control features we need like branching, diffing and merging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Pure** content shouldn't need to live under source control. You can have versioning against the content via SharePoint.
If you're talking about the masterpages and page layouts, then you can happily keep these under source control and deploy the changed files via a module in a feature with code to ensure the overwrite happens and package in a solution.
If you absolutely must have the content under source control then you could just extract the content using the Content Deployment Wizard (look on CodePlex) or some other means and source control that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SharePoint designer to check out, check in and publish html content on aspx pages. SharePoint Designer 2010 version is free and if you have access to the SharePoint site then you can modify the content too.
Download SharePoint designer [here](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/en-us/product/Related-Technologies/Pages/SharePoint-Designer.aspx)

Having said that, you can also use SharePoint out of the box versioning, check in, check out functionalities. Most of the content in SharePoint end up in a list/library, including the pages. (like pages library in a sharepoint site).

See [this](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/work-with-pages-in-a-publishing-site-HA010099663.aspx), [this](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/create-sharepoint-site-pages-HA101782505.aspx) and [this](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/introduction-to-sharepoint-master-pages-HA102019628.aspx)